# Python Split a 3 Digit Number in Two Parts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code based on the Chocolate Math game (http://www.joe-ks.com/Chocolate_Math.htm). I can get the code to run fine, except for the very last part.

I want the output to read, for example, "Your final number is 533. That means your original number was 5 and you are 33 years old."

What I can't figure out is how to print only the last two digits of the three digit number.

```
    orig_num = int(input("Okay, tell me how many times a week you want chocolate. It should be more than one, but less than 10: "))

    guess = ((orig_num * 2) + 5) * 50

    birthday = input("Have you had your birthday this year? Y/N: ")
    if birthday == 'Y':
        guessb = guess + current_year - 250
    elif birthday == 'N':
        guessb = guess + current_year - 251

    year = int(input("What year were you born? (Don't worry, I won't look): "))
    less_year = guessb - year

    print("Well! Your number is {}. That means your original number was {}, and you are {} years old".format(less_year, orig_num, less_year))
```

I feel as though I should have a function in here somewhere, but I'm too green to know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to solve it - one would be to use modulus, i.e. `533%100=33` or you can just treat it as a string an select last 2 digits `str(533)[-2:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? Not sure I really understand what you're trying to accomplish here, but the output I achieve with this seems to be in line with what you have described.

Although, it should be noted that your age (in years) for the person has the potential to be off since you aren't taking into account months / offset.

e.g. For input: I want chocolate 3 days a week, I haven't had a birthday this year was born in '96 and the output is:

```
Okay, tell me how many times a week you want chocolate.
It should be more than one, but less than 10: 3

Have you had your birthday this year? Y/N: N
What year were you born? (Don't worry, I won't look): 1996
Well! Your number is 319. That means your original number was 3, and you are 19 years old
```

That should be 20 ;)

I'm assuming that's what the `250` and `251` is for and in that case they should be switched? Again, not sure since as of right now they're magic numbers.

```
orig_num = int(input("Okay, tell me how many times a week you want chocolate. It should be more than one, but less than 10: "))

guess = ((orig_num * 2) + 5) * 50
current_year = 2016
birthday = input("Have you had your birthday this year? Y/N: ")
if birthday == 'Y':
    guessb = guess + current_year - 250
elif birthday == 'N':
    guessb = guess + current_year - 251

year = int(input("What year were you born? (Don't worry, I won't look): "))
less_year = guessb - year
orig_num = (less_year - orig_num) // 100
age = less_year % 100

print("Well! Your number is {}. That means your original number was {}, and you are {} years old".format(less_year, orig_num, age))
```